# How to make repeated intermitten movement while holding "x" key --> LUA --- LOGITECH

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I got this code that makes my mouse drag down if i press mouse 5 while numlock is active, but i want to make my mouse go right and press D at same time for half a second then switch to mouse left and press A at same time and keep repeating this untill i stop pressing mouse5 --- Mouse 5 is IsMouseButtonPressed(5) if youre not familiar with the API

```
 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
            repeat
                MoveMouseRelative(0,5)
                Sleep(5)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end             
    end
end
```

How do i make it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
local keydir = {[-1]="A", [1]="D"}
local speed = 1

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
      local dir = -1
      repeat
         dir = -dir
         local time0 = GetRunningTime()
         repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(dir*speed, 0)
            Sleep(15)
         until GetRunningTime() - time0 > 500
         PressAndReleaseKey(keydir[dir])
         Sleep(15)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
   end
end
```

Comment: Got stuck in something like that. Even tought Thats straight what i asked i didnt explain myself very well but the movemouse need to be split in like 1ms like cant be 10 big chunks of movement each 15 ms needs to be like 1 small chunk every 1 ms and the sync between left movement and A key and right movement and D key must be perfect? is there any change that could achieve this goals?

Comment: `sync between left movement and A key` - what do you mean?  The mouse moves constantly, the key is pressed once.  How to sync them?

Comment: When the A key is being pressed the left MoveMouseRelative should switch to right MoveMouseRelative at the exact same time like A and Left mouse movement should stop exactly at same time and R and right mouse Move should start at exact same time then stop then go in perfect sync and it also needs to go vertically up at a third of the horizontal move speed when moving right and vertically down at a third of the speed or 40% whatever when moving left. Cant figure my way around that

Comment: Answer updated.  Is left/right/A/D correct now?

Comment: Can you find a way to make it hold the keys instead of taping, Cant figure a way around it

Comment: You can use `PressKey` and `ReleaseKey` instead of `PressAndReleaseKey` if you want to keep key pressed for some time.